# UItextfield Deleting text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sdk

I have a weird problem.

I have 3 section tableview

one i have taken uitextfield , one is type button and last one is search button .

The problem is suppose i am typing "Boston" on uitextfield and then when i tap to button type (another View) where i can select type of search after selecting type when i come back to home where i have typed Boston in uitextfield it is gone away i mean it becomes blank then again i have to type Boston how can i keep that as it is coming from type view to home view with out auto delete from anything textfield.

Please Help

Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

I will have to reload the table view because what ever type i am selecting is displayed on the button as a lable subview and the button is on tableview therefore to show that i will have to reload tableview but reloading the tableview also reloads uitextfield part.

is there any thing like we can specify that which section should reload or something like that

Thanks is advance

Comment: Are you reloading tableview when coming from type view?Then you have to save textfield value in some string and display that string when coming back to home view.

Comment: You may be re initiating the previous view where you have typed when you returning from the "search type selection" , so the component is new, Two solution, 1. You should not re-create/initiate  the view again for not leaving the text you entered and 2. better before going for selection take the text field value and keep it in local and after coming back from the selection read and display the value in textField. Hope this can help you out

Answer (score 0):

It's a liitle bit hard without more info but -

1) Have you confirmed that the textfield's delegate doesn't delete the textfield? check the textfield did finish editing.

2) Put a breakpoint in the first tableview. In the cell for tableviewcell, maybe your tableview is reloaded and you replace the textfield with a new one.

Goog luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be saving the value of the `UITextField` as you go to your type of search button. In your `viewWillAppear:` method you repopulate that text.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if([tmpText length] > 0)
       [yourTextField setText:tmpText];
}


-(void)typeOfSearchAction {
  ....
  tmpText = [yourTextField text];
}
```

So now when you get the viewWillAppear call, assuming it's in a different `UIViewController` you can re-populate the text. Otherwise you can take the logic, and still store the UITextField's text value to a string.

Answer (score 0):

When popping the main view, i think you are reloading table or UITextField's text in -(void)viewWillApear{} method. Do not reload table or UITextField's text in viewWillApear{}. It will reset the values associated with the table cell or UITextField, as when you pop a viewController, viewWillApear method is called.

Hope this helps..